# How to do an addition between two fraction matrix

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a Matrix class with `fillMatrix()` and `printMatex()` methods, it is fraction matrix and filled by using hashmap :  `HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<Number>>` (with rows and colomns format)

Number is a class with addition and subtraction of fraction methods.
I asked to make a method in `Matrix` class to do addition between two matrices as the following:

> The class has a public void `addMatrices (Matrix, Matrix)` which has 2 matrices as arguments and it calculates the summation of these matrices.

I wrote this code but it didn't work. It gives me this error:

```
Incompatible types: ArrayList<Number>cannot be converted  to Number
```

Here is my code

```
  public void addMatrices(Matrix m1, Matrix m2) {    
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Number>> matrix3 = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Number>>();

    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Number>> matrix1 = m1.hMap;
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Number>> matrix2 = m2.hMap;

    Number ob = new Number();

    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j <= cols; j++) {
        matrix3.put(i, ob.addition(matrix1.get(j), matrix2.get(j)));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: please show the code for the matrix class

Comment: do I write it as comment it is too long but I can show addition method in Number class                                                                                                    public Number addition(Number no1, Number no2) {
    numerator=(no1.numerator*no2.denominator)+(no2.numerator*no1.denominator);
    denominator=no1.denominator*no2.denominator;
  
   
        for(int i=denominator;i>=1;i--){
            if(numerator%i==0&&denominator%i==0){
                numerator=numerator/i;
                denominator=denominator/i;
            }
        }
    
    
    return this;
    }

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that your variable `matrix3` is of type

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Number>>
```

if you want to put a value into the hashmap the the following types are exepected

```
put(Integer as key, ArrayList<Number> as value);
```

But you call the addition method of the number class and put the result as value into the put method and i think the result is also a number. \

So the problem is the line:

```
matrix3.put(i, ob.addition(matrix1.get(j),matrix2.get(j)));
```

Either you change the matrix3 type to

```
HashMap<Integer, Number>
```

Or you put an arraylist as value after the addition:

```
List<Numbers> n = new ArrayList<Number>();
n.add(ob.addition(matrix1.get(j),matrix2.get(j)));
matrix3.put(i, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error condition it appears that you forgot to get the rows out of the matrix. Something like

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
  ArrayList<Number> row1 = matrix1.get(i);
  ArrayList<Number> row2 = matrix2.get(i);
  for (int j = 0; j <= cols; j++) {
    matrix3.put(i, ob.addition(row1.get(j), row2.get(j)));
  }
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: amit: it gives me red underline of iterator();

Comment: llogiq: gave me the same comment Incompatible

Comment: I think the problem is when I send the Nomerator and Denomerator,the addition deals with them separately the but "/" between them but when I send it as a value from matrix it goes like 2/5 as object

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add two `ArrayList`s, instead of two `Number`s, you are basically missing one loop:

(java like pseudo code):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
   Iterator<Number> iter1 = matrix1.iterator();
   Iterator<Number> iter2 = matrix2.iterator();
   ArrayList<Number> current = new ArrayList<>();
   while (iter1.hasNext()) {
     current.add(ob.addition(iter1.next(), iter2.next());
   }
   matrix3.put(current);
}
```

As a side note, you should probably also verify dimensions of two matrices before performing this operation.

Comment: Zelldon: you are right when I send fraction from the matrex it goes like 2/3 but the addition method receive the fraction like (2,3) so what should I do to solve this problem